# Django add file and select automatic employe id

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to add documents to an employee's profile in a form but I would like the form to automatically select the employe id (Matricule), anyone have the solution?

models.py

```
class Employe(models.Model):
Matricule = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
Prenom = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
Nom = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
Tel = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
Adresse = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Courriel = models.EmailField(max_length = 254)

class Document(models.Model):
employe = models.ForeignKey(Employe, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
Description = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
Fichier = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/')
```

views.py

```
def createDocument(request, id):
employe = Employe.objects.only('Matricule')

forms = documentForm(instance=employe)

if request.method == 'POST':
    forms = documentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if forms.is_valid():
        forms.save()
        return redirect('/employe')

context = {'forms':forms}
return render(request, 'accounts/document_form.html', context)
```

[Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zP6RK.png)
[Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWwcR.png)

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
def createDocument(request, id):
    data = get_object_or_404(Employe, id=id)
    form = documentForm(instance=data)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = documentForm(request.POST, instance=data)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/employe')
     context = {
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, 'accounts/document_form.html', context)
```

Comment: On my side this do nothing, Employe ID is still not filled.

Comment: By default django will add that field.